# Object values giving array of objects in linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to query in linq and the data is coming as expected but its coming as each object of my array is again coming as array of object so I'll have to select 0th object of perticular object every time , How to get the value in proper format.
attaching my query... Thanks in advance

```
var results = (
    from site
    in db.Sites.Where(s => s.CompanyId == UserRecord.Company.CompanyId)
    join station
    in db.Stations.Include(y => y.Machines).Where(a => stationIds.Count() == 0 || stationIds.Contains(a.Id))
    on site.Id equals station.SiteId
    where ((noSearchParam || station.Name.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())) && (siteIds.Count() == 0 || siteIds.Contains(site.Id)))
    select station.Machines
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently using `select station.Machines` which I assume is a collection. You're selecting that for *each* `station`, so the result is a sequence of collections.

You can flatten the results easily though. Either replace `select station.Machines` with

```
from machine in station.Machines
select machine
```

Or keep your current query expression, and just change what you do afterwards to:

```
.SelectMany(m => m).ToList();
```